# i got Undefined index: file error in pdf php

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("pdf");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") &&
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) 
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 20000000) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
  }
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
  ?>
```

i am a newbie at php and studying pdf upload . can somebody have an idea what is wrong with my code . i have been researching . thank you so much

```
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

here is my form please somebody help me i am kind of confuse right now .

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\mangauniverse2\includes\add_pdf.php on line 3

Comment: on the top of PHP code add `if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ // add all upload code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are posting on the same file which actually generates the HTML.

So when you first generate your HTML, you don't have any posted values, so the script throws this error.

try this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file']){
    upload_file();
}else{
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php    
}
function upload_file(){
$allowedExts = array("pdf");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") &&
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) 
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 20000000) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
  }
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
}
  ?>
```

Comment: how can i save it on my phpmyadmin ?

Comment: First this is another question, and then you'll have to give it a shot by yourself, I'm not your personal developper unless you pay me. :)

Comment: you're welcome as long as you remember to click the "V" on the left side of my post ;)